# if launching an activity from another activity, should a new thread be used

Tags: android, performance

activityA launches activityB, which contains 2 fragments(master detail flow). Should a new thread be used to launch activityB? what are the pros and cons of it?

I tried it in my app, doesnt seem to hurt anything, but i am looking for the best design practice. I know that any thing which takes more than 2-3 seconds to do, should be given a new thread.

Comment: I would still start the new Activity in the main thread. If it takes too much time, then you should perhaps investigate what is taking so much time (check the methods onCreate, onResume and onStart of your Activity and the view complexity of your xml).
If you start on another thread, then the user may in fact start several activities (if he clicks a button multiple times, which is in fact even worse than a freeze of 2-3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `startActivity(intentToStart);` on main thread.
There is no any pros or cons

Answer (score 0):

Any activity stuff has to be run in the UI thread, so you should always launch an activity in the main thread. If you have to do anything time consuming then that should be threaded, but you will need to do all the user interface stuff in the UI thread or it will crash.